# ERROR Error:Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular

I looked at similar questions, but none of them helped me. I am going to receive an object like the following:

```
    {
      "_embedded": {
        "students": [
          {
            "firstName": "mohamed",
            "lastName": "najib",
            "email": "najib@gmail.com",
            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "http://localhost:9091/students/1"
              },
              "student": {
                "href": "http://localhost:9091/students/1"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "firstName": "shymaa",
            "lastName": "alaa",
            "email": "shymaa@orange.com",
            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "http://localhost:9091/students/81"
              },
              "student": {
                "href": "http://localhost:9091/students/81"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "firstName": "yasmen",
            "lastName": "gamal",
            "email": "yasmeen@orange.com",
            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "http://localhost:9091/students/88"
              },
              "student": {
                "href": "http://localhost:9091/students/88"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "firstName": "yasmen",
            "lastName": "gamal",
            "email": "yasmeen@orange.com",
            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "http://localhost:9091/students/89"
              },
              "student": {
                "href": "http://localhost:9091/students/89"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://localhost:9091/students{?page,size,sort}",
          "templated": true
        },
        "profile": {
          "href": "http://localhost:9091/profile/students"
        }
      },
      "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 4,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
      }
    }
```

and here is my http service to receive it:

```js
    getAll(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:9091/students');
      }
```

and finally, in the i called the service in this way:

```js
    Students:Array<any>;
      constructor(private service:StudentServeService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getAll().subscribe(data => {
          this.Students = data;
        });
      }
```

my component template is :

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let s of Students">
          <td>{{s.id}}</td>
          <td>{{s.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{s.lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{s.email}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Unfortunately, when the page loads it complains with:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

So, what is going wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@najib..  [**`*ngFor`**](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-ngfor/) only deals with arrays not the Object and in this case Students is an Object.

I think are you are looking to display the students array, for that you need to make some changes like below

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let s of Students?._embedded?.students">
          <td>{{s.id}}</td>
          <td>{{s.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{s.lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{s.email}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Use **safe navigation operator**(?) to check that you're sure that **Students** is not null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You made a very small mistake. ***ngFor** works on arrays, not on objects (although all arrays are objects in javascript), and your ***ngFor** is pointing to the whole response object, not to the students key of the object.
Change your binding to this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let s of Students._embedded.students">
      <td>{{s.id}}</td>
      <td>{{s.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{s.lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{s.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'students' of undefined

Comment: Just as you missed in your code, I also missed _embedded in my answer. It would e Students._embedded.students